# Regex constraint for a number range, with limit to 3 decimal places

Tags: javascript, regex

For input validation (constraining the user so that they cannot type a wrong input) I would like to create a regex in JavaScript that constrains so that:

There are two numbers, separated by a hyphen, each number can have a decimal point on the end, followed by up to three numbers (3dp)

anything typing up to this should pass the regex, so;

```
0
02
023.
023.2
023.22
023.223-
023.223-3
023.223-33
023.223-333
023.223-333.
023.223-333.3
023.223-333.33
023.223-333.333
```

are all valid values, anything outside of this format should be invalid, for example;

```
0.2343
0.233-0.2343
```

I have got some success validating the numbers either side of the hyphen;

```
^\d*\.?(\d{1,3})?$
```

Then I include this for both sides with a hyphen in the middle;

```
^\d*\.?(\d{1,3})?\-?\d*\.?(\d{1,3})?$
```

Check it here: https://regex101.com/r/klw01G/1

The issue with this solution is that it allows the first number set to have unlimited decimal places. I am confused because it applies as expected to the second set, limiting to 3dp.

What is the solution to limit the first set to 3dp? Must there be a conditional based on the `.` character?

Answer (score 2):

You need to nest optional groups:

```
^\d+(?:\.\d{0,3}(?:-(?:\d+(?:\.\d{0,3})?)?)?)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CgbhJ6/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%7B0%2C3%7D(%3F%3A-(%3F%3A%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%7B0%2C3%7D)%3F)%3F)%3F)%3F%24):

[image]

If you need to allow an empty string, too, wrap the whole part between the `^` and `$` anchors with an optional group:

```
^(?:\d+(?:\.\d{0,3}(?:-(?:\d+(?:\.\d{0,3})?)?)?)?)?$
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d{0,3}(?:-(?:\d+(?:\.\d{0,3})?)?)?)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\.\d{0,3}` - `.` and 0 to 3 digits
  - `(?:-(?:\d+(?:\.\d{0,3})?)?)?` - an optional sequence of
  - `-` -  a  hyphen
  - `(?:\d+(?:\.\d{0,3})?)?` - an optional sequence of

    - `\d+` - 1+ digits
    - `(?:\.\d{0,3})?` - an optional sequence of a dot and then 0 to 3 digits
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Think one ident answer enough and yours was earlier and that's how it works here to be fair + :)